# I can not connect to my server via another computer

Tags: java, serversocket

I am writing a program to eventually make my own file server. I am having issues with connecting to the server in a web browser via typing `myIpAddress:port` into the browser while the server is running. This does work if I use one computer to both host the server and be a client, but does not if I use a second computer to be a client.

I have 2 classes, `Index` and `ClientHandler`

```
public class Index {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ServerSocket server = null;
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(8080);
        DevInterface myFace = new DevInterface(server);
        System.out.println("Listening for connection on port 8080");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int i = 0;
    while(true) {
        Socket client = null;
        try {
            client = server.accept();
            ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(client);
            clientHandler.start();
            System.out.println("got a client");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
}
```

and my ClientHandler class which is what sends my html to the server is this.

```
public class ClientHandler extends Thread{
private Socket client = null;
private PrintWriter out = null;
ArrayList<Socket> clientList = null;
public ClientHandler(Socket client) {
    this.client = client;
}
public ClientHandler(Socket client, ArrayList<Socket> clientList) {
    this.client = client;
    this.clientList = clientList;
}
public void run() {
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
        out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
        out.println("\r\n");
        out.println("<p>Hello World</p>");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        if(client!=null) {client.close();}
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a firewall running on the server?

Comment: I am pretty new to ServerSocket, and servers in general, I don't believe I have a firewall running, however Im also not sure how to check if I do.

Comment: Are the two machines on the same network? Can you `ping` the Server machine from Client? You didn't use `127.0.0.1:port`, did you?

Comment: They are on the same network, I did not use the exact `127.0.0.1` address, but I did use my IP address

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: Yes I am on windows

Comment: Try: <WindowsKey>+r , enter "cmd". A command prompt should open. There you type `ping whateveryourIPaddressis<Enter>` (<= of course you use the actual IP). Tell us what happens. Do it on the client machine., not the server but use the server's IP.

Comment: It said it was pinging my ip address with 32 bytes of data then it said request timed out 4 times and then it said ping statistics `Packets: sent = 4, Recieved = 0, List = 4 (100% loss)`

Comment: A word of caution.  A host not responding to ping does not necessarily mean it isn't reachable.  I'm not familiar with Windows, but on Mac and Linux, it's easy to turn off responding to pings.  I don't know how likely it is that ping responses would be disabled, but just know ping isn't a panacea

Comment: OK. Then it is not an issue of your code. Your client machine doesn't seem to be able to reach the server. That can mean they are on different networks or segments. And the firewall isn't off the hook, neither.

Comment: Great! Is there anything you would recommend me to do to try and fix it?

Comment: @Steve You are correct. ICMP may be blocked. Still, if so, then other ports are likely to be blocked, too. That would encourage to investigate in direction of a firewall.

Comment: Just for curiosity, you could do the same ping on the server using the client's IP ... as Steve correctly states, it failing is not _much_ of a hint but it _succeeding_ would be very revealing.

Comment: I just pinged the client from the server, and I got the same message as I got from pinging the server computer from the client computer

Comment: What Windows Versions are they running on? Do you know how to lookup the network settings? If so, lookup both and check: subnet mask. Is it the same on both? Also check IP-Addresses. Do they have the same values in the places where the mask has "255" ?

Comment: ^^ For example if they both have Mask of `255.255.255.0` do both IPs start with for example `192.168.0.XXX` ( where XXX may be different values on both)

Comment: I am running windows 10 on both systems, and I do know how to find the network settings, both systems are on the same network.

Comment: Then type "firewall" into the search field in the task bar of the server. See if you can find settings that block any traffic.

Comment: Ok I just looked up the fire wall and I didn't realize but apparently I do have one. It looks like my antivirus software installed it. Would I need to just disconnect the firewall for this to work? Or maybe run it on a system with out a firewall?

Comment: Have a search for your firewall and how to permit access to specific ports. You may be able to use common service names rather than port numbers, but you'll always be able to permit a specific port through. You will need admin privileges.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help, I will look that up now.

Comment: I once had an Anti-Virus that happily accepted TCP connections on _all_ not occupied ports, so a test to see if our application was up and running by trying to make a "dummy" connection failed miserably... Always a good idea to check up on installed Anti-Virus suites and how they behave.